# How solve: Underfull \vbox (badness 6876) has occurred while \output is active

Tags: errors, debugging

I am solving all my warnings/errors in my document. I have solved everything except for 2:

> Underfull \vbox (badness 6876) has occurred while \output is active
>   [18]

and

> Underfull \vbox (Badness 2142) has occurred while \output is active
>   [30]

My first question:

- How can I found out where this error occurs? Is [18] and [30] the pagenumber? I cannot find anything strage there.
- How can I get more information where error occurs? Is there a debug option (like for overfull).

I found already this [question:](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229667/detection-of-underfull-vbox-hbox) with debug option:

```
\showboxbreadth=50 
\showboxdepth=50
```

But that did not help.

How to deal with this?

Comment: You have two pages that are not adequately filled up. Check what comes at the top of page 19, it's probably something that can't be split across pages. Usually this is solved with `\enlargethispage` tricks on a couple of facing pages, so as to make room for some more material (or less).